# FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

To get the data from the firestore collection for instance update I tried the below query.

docRef.whereArrayContains().orderBy().limit()

com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here:

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.

[Manage indexes in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing)

When you get the error check LogCat for the link